# IllegalMoniterStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I get an illegalMoniterStateException whenever I call wait() and notify() or notifyAll(). The javadoc says that I should be getting that exception if my thread "has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor."

However, here is an example of the code where I call those methods above.

```
//note that doSomething will be called by a thread from another class, not this one
public void doSomething(){
    while(objectsCurrentlyDoingSomething() >= thisClass'sCapacity){
         synchronized(objectLock){ //objectLock is created at top of class like this:
             wait(2000);           //private static final Object objectLock = new Object();
         }
    }

    //rest of code
}
```

Then later on I release one threads hold on that lock by saying that if object finishes, decreases number of objects currently using and notify().

```
....object finished......
synchronized(objectLock){
    notify();
}
```

Comment: Does objectLock in both places refer to same monitor?

Comment: @Nambari I don't fully understand what a monitor is so I googled it. Wikipedia says that "In concurrent programming, a monitor is an object or module intended to be used safely by more than one thread. The defining characteristic of a monitor is that its methods are executed with mutual exclusion. That is, at each point in time, at most one thread may be executing any of its methods." objectLock is a final static Object() that cannot be changed, however the class it's called in can have more than one thread executing it's methods at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call wait, and notify on objectLock.

e.g.

`objectLock.wait()`

It you just call `wait()` you are calling it on `this`.

Comment: Even though I want the current thread to wait 1 second, release it's hold on the lock thus allowing other threads to call this method and also wait() if need be?

Comment: That was example code. You can still pass a desired parameter to wait. The important point is to call it on the synchronized object (objectLock in your case).

Answer (score 1):

As noted by z5h, your calls to wait() and notify() should be made on the objectLock object:

```
//note that doSomething will be called by a thread from another class, not this one
public void doSomething(){
    while(objectsCurrentlyDoingSomething() >= thisClass'sCapacity){
         synchronized(objectLock){ //objectLock is created at top of class like this:
             objectLock.wait(2000);           //private static final Object objectLock = new Object();
         }
    }

    //rest of code
}
```

and

```
....object finished......
synchronized(objectLock){
    objectLock.notify();
}
```